# How to include Area within a route

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following in my WebApiConfig

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
 {           
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));           
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",                                
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:15880", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

    }
```

and now within ProductAreaRegistration

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: this.AreaName,                
           routeTemplate: "api/" + this.AreaName + "/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        context.MapRoute(
            "Product_default",
            "Product/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }                
        );
    }
```

Now I have the following in my WebApi Controller..

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct()
    {
        try
        {
            var product = db.Products.Take(5);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok(product );
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }

    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(long id)
    {
        try 
        {
            var product = db.Products.Find(id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(product );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Now here when I try to make a request

```
http://localhost:15877/Api/PT/GetProducts/1 it successfully get invoked
```

the Get Method with parameter and also when I say

```
http://localhost:15877/Api/GetProducts/1 it works fine
```

and when I say

```
http://localhost:15877/Api/GetProducts it gets me list of Products and when I say

http://localhost:15877/Api/PT/GetProducts it says
{"$id":"1","Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of...
```

Is there something I am missing. My basic idea is to get the list or a single object by passing the Area name and here PT is an Area. Can you please tell me what should I do to make it work when I say

```
http://localhost:15877/Api/PT/GetProducts
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you registering your areas in the Global.asax?

Comment: @Noel yeah, registered areas within Global.asax